# Very basic Q regarding for Loops in Python

Tags: for-loop, python-2.7

I am learning Python so this is a very basic question that keeps on bothering me regarding *for* loops. Below is a very simple loop.

```
def rot13(entry):
    for each_word in entry:
        return each_word

print rot13("hello")
```

When I run this, my output is "h". I know *for* loops always go through each character of the string, so I am confused why it just prints the first character vs the entire string. How do I get it to print "hello", as one string, after passing through the for loop? Thanks in advance for helping a novice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you're `return`ing `each_word`, you're returning the letter `h` only, then the function stops.

Consider it like this:

```
def rot13(entry):
    for each_word in entry: # Starts with h
        print each_word
        # Prints h
        return each_word
        # Returns the letter h. Breaks.
```

To print the whole word, you could just `return entry` and not use a for loop at all. Or if you want to print each letter then return the word, put the return statement outside of the for loop:

```
def rot13(entry):
    for each_word in entry:
        print each_word
    return entry
```

And when called:

```
>>> rot13('hello')
h
e
l
l
o
'hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

the statement

```
 return each_word
```

makes the control to return to the call statement. So that only the first element `h` is printed. use

```
def rot13(entry):
    for each_word in entry:
        print each_word,
```

to print the whole word. Or to return the whole word, just use `return entry`